# What is the default keyboard shortcut for opening Selenium IDE from within Firefox

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

I'm sure this is documented somewhere obvious, but I just can't find it.

I'm currently switching back and forth between Firefox and Selenium using a toolbar button, but it's annoyingly slow to keep having to use the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to hack one into existence, so you can do this if you are comfortable with it.

In the version I'm using (1.4.1) open "chrome\content\selenium-ide-overlay.xul"
Near the bottom there is this code:

```
  <!--
  <keyset id="mainKeyset">
    <key id="key_viewSeleniumIDESidebar" command="viewSeleniumIDESidebar" 
     key="S" modifiers="alt,accel"/>
  </keyset>
  -->
```

Which means it already is there, they've just commented it out for some reason.
I took out the comments and replaced the sidebar command with one from above so it has its own window like normal

```
  <keyset id="mainKeyset">
    <key id="key_viewSeleniumIDESidebar" oncommand="SeleniumIDE.Loader.openRecorder();"
     keycode="VK_F11" modifiers="alt,accel"/>
  </keyset>
```

Once I've refreshed the browser I can use ctrl-alt-F11 to bring up selenium. (the change from 'key' to 'keycode' lets you use non-printable keys, so keep it 'key' if you want it to br a printable character; you can get the keycodes from:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Keyboard_Shortcuts#Keycode_attribute

Note the 'accel' key differs from platform to platform (also explained in the link above)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's a default keyboard shortcut but i press the following sequence

```
Alt - t - n
```

Which opens the tools sub menu, and then "n" opens or switches to selenium

Comment: does alt then t bring up the tools submenu?

Comment: Nice worked for me, holding alt down, press t, let it go, then n, yeppers!  what i was looking for. cause it keps opening in sidebar, i want it in new window by default, for for some reason i cant figure out how to get it out of sidebar otherwise till this command.  geese, to each his own i guess.  thanks.  Essentially thats the hotkey thats printed in the menu, and this is opens ff's menu `alt` ,  select dev tools `t` then selenium's key `n`.  Very good, thumbs up, thats what google is for. :-)

Comment: doesnt work for mac, works perfect for win7 latest ff

Answer (score 3):

The answer is to hold down CTRL ALT S